# How to display an array of strings in react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to display an array of strings on separate lines in my react component by doing the following:

```
       <div>
          {this.props.notifications.join('\n')}
      </div>
```

However, this doesn't seem to be working. this.props.notifications is an array of strings that I want to render in the div. Does anyone know how I can work around this?

Comment: What about using  `this.props.notifications.join();` ?

Comment: What do you mean by "this doesn't seem to be working"? It works in some way. What way do you want it to work?

Comment: @Aaron I want each string to be on a separate line. I tried using .join('\n') but that doesn't seem to do the trick. I updated my question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What about using a `<p />` to render each line?

```
<div>
   {this.props.notifications.map(txt => <p>{txt}</p>)}
</div>
```

That will render each element in a different paragraph.

Answer (score 4):

> I want each string to be on a separate line.

Use `Array/map()` in your render:

```
<div>
  { this.props.notifications.map(notification => <p>{ notification }</p>) }
</div>
```

Comment: I've tried that, but it only words if I'm mapping over an array of numbers. If I use an array of strings, it puts them all together side-by-side, even though the individual <p></p> is clearly defined

Answer (score 2):

You can use [string literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) or `\n`.
But you will need to combine it with the css rule:

```
white-space: pre-line;
```

Here is a running example with string literals:

```js
const arr = ['this is line #1', 'this is line #2', 'this is line #3']
const App = () => (
  <div className="line-break">
    {
      arr.map(str => {
        return(`
          ${str}
        `)
      })
    }
  </div>
);

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```css
.line-break {
  white-space: pre-line;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Here is a running example with `\n`:

```js
const arr = ['this is line #1', 'this is line #2', 'this is line #3']
const App = () => (
  <div className="line-break">
    {
      arr.join('\n')
    }
  </div>
);

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```css
.line-break {
  white-space: pre-line;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```