# Q: Render array of strings in react js

Tags: reactjs, firebase, jsx

I have an array of strings and I'm trying to render it inside a component with react js

this array of comments is inside my Posts

comentarios = ["test1", "test2", "test3","test4"]
note: I'm taking this array from firebase documents

I can render it but I have a problem. when I render by map () this array returns me all the items in a single line. I researched some resolutions for this problem here in the community and on google, I found this topic: [How to display an array of strings in react component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48215965/how-to-display-an-array-of-strings-in-react-component)

even so, I was unable to resolve it definitively.

my question is: how do i return each index of the array within its own paragraph?

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      Posts: [],
    }

 <div className="text-comentarios">    
     {this.state.Posts.map( (itens,index) =>{
         <div>
           <p key={index}> {itens.comentarios} </p>
         </div>
       )
       })}
 </div>
```

I am have the return of this map as follows:

```
Coments: test1test2test3test4
```

how do i get this return, example:

```
Coments: test1
Coments: test2
Coments: test3
Coments: test4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can map the comments like you did with the posts

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      Posts: [],
    }

 <div className="text-comentarios">    
     {this.state.Posts.map( (itens,index) =>{
         <div>
           <div key={index}>
             {itens.commentarios.map((comment, commentIndex) => <p key={commentIndex}>{comment}</p> )}
           </div>
         </div>
       })}
 </div>
```

Comment: thank you for giving me this help and taking time to help me

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have set display: inline or flex property in .text-commentarios or above parent class. Please remove that property to display as rows not inline.
And you code containes )} at the end which is needless try to remove that and change code as below. And use span tag instead of p tag to display as inline in div element.
And then you need to change code a little

```
{this.state.Posts.map( (itens,index) =>{
     <div key={index}>
         <span class="row-title"> Comments: </span>
         <span> {itens.comentarios} </span>
     </div>
  })
}
```

Hope this helps you to understand!

Comment: I will try this and then come back with feedback